# "Cannot import name Popen" in IronPython 2.7.3

Tags: ironpython

I'm having a weird problem where, even though I do a "clr.AddReference('IronPython.Stdlib')" at the top of some IronPython code (I do have a built copy of StdLib readily findable), I am unable to access Popen. This is a multithreaded application, where many threads (ten, right now) are trying to access this script at the same time.

I don't have a problem accessing it from IronPython at the console.

```
2013-09-03 17:10:11.5197 Error PythonScriptEngineProviderLib.PythonScriptEngineProvider.ExecuteCompiledCodeInternal Could not execute Python code. IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException: Cannot import name Popen
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportFrom(CodeContext context, Object from, String name)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`4.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run2[T0,T1,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
   at IronPython.Compiler.PythonScriptCode.RunWorker(CodeContext ctx)
   at IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.InvokeTarget(Scope scope)
   at PythonScriptEngineProviderLib.PythonScriptEngineProvider.ExecuteCompiledCodeInternal(CompiledCode cc, IDictionary`2 scopeVariables) in 
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I don't have a solution for this (I am the OP), it appears that it's only a problem that occurs at process startup. It starts working after a suitable waiting period. Although I am not sure what that period is, I see that the subroutines that depend on it are working as expected a few minutes later (they wait, and then reattempt later when experiencing failure).

Since this is a long-running process, this problem shouldn't have a significant cost, for now. However, if I had to guess, it seems like StdLib may have a loading delay that may block the initiating thread, but not the others.